# How To Make a Virtual SIM For Genymotion

Tags: java, android, plugins, whatsapp, genymotion

I am trying to develop an application that will download the Status just after seeing in WhatsApp (whether it may be an Image or Video). When I open WhatsApp on my Genymotion then it asks me to enter my phone number. Whenever I fulfill all the requirements then it does not show any of the Status.

It may be because for the first time I am using my number on WhatsApp. I ask my friends to upload their Images or Videos in their status menu, but it can't show me their status. Is there any plugin out there that can make a virtual SIM for this purpose.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are compatibility issues with WhatsApp on Genymotion 3.1.0 for the moment. You may try with Google emulator instead or wait for Genymotion 3.1.1.

Comment: Can you tell me if someone uploads their images or videos, then can I see their Status or not, if I run the WhatsApp app on Android Emulator using my own number?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not familiar with Google Android Emulator. You should open a new topic about Google Android Emulator so that others may help you.